# Dynamically change default route parameters in zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-route, zend-translate

I need to change my language application dynamically.
I have the folowing route configuration:

```
'route'    => '/[:lang[/:controller[/:action[/:id]]]][[/page/:page]]',

'defaults' => array(
'lang'     => 'en',
        ),
```

Is it possible to change the parameter 'lang' from my controller or from my Module.php (function onBootstrap). I don't know if I can use a globale variable or something similar.

```
'defaults' => array(
'lang'     => $my_variable,
        ),
```

If it is possible how can I change it ?

Thaks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem and figured it out, try:

```
$e->getRouter()->setDefaultParam('lang', 'de_DE');
```

I'm triggering this on MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH (see update note below) with the use of a listener, but onBootstrap in `Module.php` should work too.

**Update:**

Ok, now I see that `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` is **too late** for applying a default parameter to the Router. Especially when You're interested not only in passing the language via route, but also in having translatable routes (in conjunction with `'router_class'=>'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack'`).

So it should be on MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE:

```
// applying a default language param to route
$e->getRouter()->setDefaultParam('lang', 'de_DE');

// Now detect the requested language or retrieve 
// from matched route
// $detectedLocale =...
// ...

// Retrieve the translator
$sm->get('translator');

// Apply detected locale to the translator
$translator->setLocale($detectedLocale);

// and now this apply the translator to the router
// for translatable routes
$e->getRouter()->setTranslator($translator);

// but don't forget about
// 'router_class'=>'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack'
// for translatable routes
```

I see people saying, that You should do this in `onBootstrap()`, but IMVHO `onBootstrap` is TOO EARLY for retrieving a `matched route`, which is required for detecting the locale/language passed by the client in a route/url parameter.

By saying "detecting the locale" I'm definitely **not thinking about** any dirty string operations on the url/query string, I'm thinking about a clean `getParam()` on the matched route.

Related:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your route setup you will always have to include the lang parameter to access anything other than the default controller.

URL: '/' will have lang 'en' and controller 'default', etc.
URL: '/es' will have lang value 'es' and controller 'default'
URL: '/es/about' will have lang value 'es' and controller 'about'
URL: '/about' will try to set lang to 'about' and probably break the route.

You can & should change the translator's language code in Module::onBootstrap. You will have access to the route parameters there through the MvcEvent object.